# 0, 800, 600, 0 vs 0, 800, 0, 600 OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, orthographic

In a 800 x 600 window, it seems like the most common way to setup the OpenGL matrix is *glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1)* while I always use *glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1)*. Is there a reason why some people prefer the first way I shown over the second?

Answer (score 6):

Most mathematical thinking folks (which most 3D coders are) assume the origin of the coordinate system to be in the lower left with increasing X and Y coordinates to right and up. Also making `top > bottom` and `right > left` keeps the chirality of the transformations; with a flipped chirality you have to adjust the winding of face culling among other things.